# Where are the deb files downloaded by Software center and the update manager stored?

Tags: software-center, deb

I want to know where the deb files that are downloaded during the installation from the software center are stored.

Its easy to download I know, but here in my country, bandwidths are extremely limited and it would be better to get the deb file for te next time rather than waiting a complete night for download!

Aslo, I would like to know where the deb files downloaded during updates are stored.?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/974/62483)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/
```

This does not mean you will be able to copy everything over to another computer and have them install without internet. normally there is a lot of dependencies needed. though it should save you from downloading large amounts of the same data.

Answer (score 3):

`/var/cache/apt/archives/` is the place. You need to be careful with dependencies.