# Where are the software update files stored, and what happens after they are applied?

Tags: updates

I have what I think is a basic question but have not been able to find the answer to:  When Software Updater downloads files (this morning it amounted to 250mb), are the files (or the ones that are outdated - for example, older kernel updates, older LibreOffice updates) automatically removed after the update finishes?
Regarding the portion of my question regarding the location that Software Updater stores them - I've had responses (thank you!) that indicate they might be located in /var/cache/apt/archives, but the links speak only to installing new packages, not updates.  Can someone confirm that the Software Updater uses this same location?

FWIW: Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Comment: [Where are the deb files downloaded by Software center and the update manager stored?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/222670/where-are-the-deb-files-downloaded-by-software-center-and-the-update-manager-sto) -- From the accepted answer: `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> sudo apt-get autoclean

It will not delete any installed packages but only clean /var/cache/apt/archive from deb-files (essentially can be used for cleaning temp files)